# ImportError: No module named django.core.management error

Tags: python, django, osx-snow-leopard

After installing Django and Python on MacOX Mountain Lion, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

when I do :

```
sudo python manage.py startapp user
```

What should I do?

Comment: did you install django inside a virtual env and forgot to activate it ?

Comment: Add the output of sys.path to your question.

Comment: I'm not an expert in OS X, but I think that `sudo` command is redundant